# How can I write a SQL query to change the order and truncate the elements in a JSON payload?

Tags: sql, json, mulesoft

I am new to SQL. I am trying to query a database so that I can get JSON output in return. I need the output to show truncated versions of the values, and also to display the keys in alphabetical order.

As an example, let's say one of the fields in the payload reads:
{color: Black w/ Yellow Trim}

How do I write a SQL query such that it only displays this:
{color: Black}

Also, how do I write the query to list the keys in alphabetical order?

Many thanks in advance.

I have not tried anything yet; I am new to SQL.

Comment: Please clarify what is the criteria for truncation. Just the first word until the first space? Also do you expect the query to return a JSON, or it is OK to do that in Mule? You used both tags, however perhaps JSON conversion is not a standard SQL feature. Kindly mention the database vendor and version just in case.

Comment: Good question. The values vary quite a bit, so I think it would be ideal to truncate by character length, if that makes sense? Yes, the JSON can be returned in Mule. I'm working with SQL Server 2016.

Comment: If you want N number of characters, you can use `substring`.  The exact syntax will depend on your specific RDBMS, but it's basically `substring(<column>,<start>,<length>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this in Mule I would use an SQL query to get the raw information and then transform it using DataWeave:

```
<flow name="selectParameterizedQuery">
     <db:select config-ref="dbConfig">
        <db:sql>SELECT color FROM colortable</db:sql> <!-- query to get the color results -->
    </db:select>
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
        <ee:message >
            <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
                %dw 2.0
                output application/json
                ---
                payload map {
                    color: $.color[0 to 4]  // get 5 first characters
                }    
     ]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
</flow>
```

Let's say that the query returns this:

```
 [{"color": "Black w/ Yellow Trim"}, {"color": "Black w/ blue Trim"}, {"color": "Red"},{"color": "Red w/ blue Trim"}]
```

Then the transformation would return:

```
[
  {
    "color": "Black"
  },
  {
    "color": "Black"
  },
  {
    "color": null
  },
  {
    "color": "Red w"
  }
]
```

Note that you still need to [configure the database connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/database/database-connector-studio) and adapt the query.

Probably you will need to experiment with different criteria for selecting the color. Note that the "Red" will return null because the substring is too short. You can use DataWeave expressions for that.

Comment: Thank you Aled! Much appreciated.